Why is my Ram cleaner android app not detecting any recently running
My ram cleaner android app is not working as expected since its not detecting the recently used apps in order for it to clean them, even though when it is launched it asks for special usage access first before scanning for recently used apps in order to clean them from the RAM .Ive enabled the kill background process and usage stats permission in android manifest file
i have tried increasing and reducing the time window from 24hrs to 5 min but its not working as it should
here is my code help me find a solution please
package com.example.systemoptimizer6;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RAMCleaner {
    private static final String TAG = "RAMCleaner";
    private final Context context;
    private final PackageManager packageManager;
    private final ActivityManager activityManager;

    public static class AppInfo {
        public final String appName;
        public final Drawable appIcon;
        public final String packageName;

        public AppInfo(String appName, Drawable appIcon, String packageName) {
            this.appName = appName;
            this.appIcon = appIcon;
            this.packageName = packageName;
        }
    }

    public RAMCleaner(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        this.activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    public List<AppInfo> getRunningApps() {
        List<AppInfo> runningApps = new ArrayList<>();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fetching apps using UsageStatsManager...");
            runningApps = getAppsFromUsageStats();
        }

        if (runningApps.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "UsageStatsManager returned no apps. Fallback to ActivityManager...");
            runningApps = getAppsFromActivityManager();
        }

        if (runningApps.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No apps detected. Ensure permissions are granted.");
        }

        return runningApps;
    }

    private List<AppInfo> getAppsFromUsageStats() {
        List<AppInfo> runningApps = new ArrayList<>();
        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeWindow = currentTime - 1000 * 60 * 5; // Last 5 minutes

        List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(
                UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
                timeWindow,
                currentTime
        );

        if (usageStatsList == null || usageStatsList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No usage stats available.");
            return runningApps;
        }

        usageStatsList.sort((u1, u2) -> Long.compare(u2.getLastTimeUsed(), u1.getLastTimeUsed()));

        for (UsageStats usageStats : usageStatsList) {
            String packageName = usageStats.getPackageName();
            try {
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);

                if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0 && !packageName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
                    Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
                    runningApps.add(new AppInfo(appName, appIcon, packageName));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Detected app: " + appName);
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "App not found: " + packageName + ", skipping.");
            }
        }

        return runningApps;
    }

    private List<AppInfo> getAppsFromActivityManager() {
        List<AppInfo> runningApps = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        if (runningProcesses == null || runningProcesses.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No running processes found.");
            return runningApps;
        }

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            String packageName = processInfo.processName;

            if (processInfo.importance > ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                continue; // Skip non-active apps
            }

            try {
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);

                if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0 && !packageName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
                    Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
                    runningApps.add(new AppInfo(appName, appIcon, packageName));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Detected app (ActivityManager): " + appName);
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "App not found: " + packageName, e);
            }
        }

        return runningApps;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    public void cleanApps(List<String> packageNames) {
        for (String packageName : packageNames) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
                Log.d(TAG, "Killed background process: " + packageName);
            }
        }
    }
}


i have managed to fix it by adding query all apps permission to my app and also adding it to the android manifest file thanks
